# Ignore SQL file for environments

Tags: maven, flyway

Can anyone advise if there is a configuration setting for flyway so that it can ignore a certain sql file depending on which environment I am migrating the database in?

I am using the maven flyway plugin and have a number of sql files for eg:

```
V1.01_schema.sql
V1.02_data.sql
V1.03_testdata.sql
```

When I move my database into production I do not want to apply the testData.sql file. Any way that I can get it to ignore this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define a specific profile that will tell [`flyway-maven-plugin`](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/) to ignore a specific execution. The idea is to split the process into 2 executions: one that will be common to environments and another one specific to the test environment. When building with the `dev` profile, the second execution will not be skipped whereas it will be skipped in the default case.

```xml
<properties>
    <flyway.prod>true</flyway.prod>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>dev</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <flyway.prod>false</flyway.prod>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>migrate-1</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>migrate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <locations>
                            <location>V1.01_schema.sql</location>
                            <location>V1.02_data.sql</location>
                        </locations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>migrate-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>migrate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${flyway.prod}</skip>
                        <locations>
                            <location>V1.03_testdata.sql</location>
                        </locations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- common configuration here -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```